# Efficiently read data from a structured file in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I have a file as follows:

[image]

The file consists of 2 parts: header and data.

The data part is separated into equally sized pages. Each page holds data for a specific metric. Multiple pages (needs not to be consecutive) might be needed to hold data for a single metric. Each page consists of a page header and a page body. A page header has a field called "Next page" that is the index of the next page that holds data for the same metric. A page body holds real data. All pages have the same & fixed size (20 bytes for header and 800 bytes for body (if data amount is less than 800 bytes, 0 will be filled)).

The header part consists of 20,000 elements, each element has information about a specific metric (point 1 -> point 20000). An element has a field called "first page" that is actually index of the first page holding data for the metric.

The file can be up to 10 GB.

Requirement: Re-order data of the file in the shortest time, that is, pages holding data for a single metric must be consecutive, and from metric 1 to metric 20000 according to alphabet order (header part must be updated accordingly).

An apparent approach: For each metric, read all data for the metric (page by page), write data to new file. But this takes much time, especially when reading data from the file.

Is there any efficient ways?

Comment: What is c/c++ ? Asking io-performance question like that makes me think you don't know what are you doing at all. Sorry.

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit system you could memory map the complete file, and basically treat it as an array of structures.

Comment: You're going to be hit by the disk IO time, more so as you're reading and writing. Get a solution that works, then look to see what the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I'm going with @JoachimPileborg. Memory mapping the whole (or parts of the) file into memory will give you better performance than fread/fseek.

Comment: Also, do you really need to actually move the data around, its not enough to just update the "next page" pointers? That will make it a *lot* quicker.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This is requirements from our customers. They gave us original files, asked us to write a program with the requirements.

Comment: Also, you're going to have to read/write the whole file as you want pages in the same metric to be consecutive. The alphabetic ordering is tricky as you've not said where the string for testing is!

Comment: You could suggest to your customer that databases have been invented

Comment: Are you *sure* that the requirement is tht the data physically should be movd around? If you think of it like a linked list, when changing the order of the nodes in a linked list you don't actually move the data around but only the link pointers. If the "next page" pointer for a page points to a page tht is not really the "next" page, does it matter? Seeking through a fie is a small operation compared to the reading/writing. Maybe you need to talk to the customer about it, and get some clarification on this?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually, in each header element there is a field called "number of pages", so if data is re-organized to be consecutive it will be more efficient to read a large block of data (number of pages) at once. Because the data will be retrieved many times in future.

Comment: Ah, that changes it of course. Efficiency of sorting versus efficiency of use. It's a tradeoff and if the tradeoff is in the favor of usage then the sorting will suffer. :)

Comment: If every page is the same size, you can go the other way entirely - first determine the "chains" of data pages by traversing the page headers sequentially, then see which metric they belong to. From those chains and the (sorted) header, you can calculate the position of each page in the final output. Then go through the file sequentially and write each page in its proper place.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I am running this on Windows x64, could you please give me some examples of memory mapping in C++ on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first read header part, then sort metrics in alphabetic order. For each metric in the sorted list I read all data from the input file and write to the output file. To remove bottlenecks at reading data step, I used memory mapping. The results showed that when using memory mapping the execution time for an input file of 5 GB was reduced 5 ~ 6 times compared with when not using memory mapping. This way temporarily solve my problems. However, I will also consider suggestions of @utnapistim.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to create an index from the file, containing the page number and the page metric that you need to sort on. Create this index as an array, so that the first entry (index `0`) corresponds to the first page, the second entry (index `1`) the second page, etc.

Then you sort the index using the metric specified.

When sorted, you end up with a new array which contains a new first, second etc. entries, and you read the input file writing to the output file in the order of the sorted index.

Comment: I don't see any difference from the approach I pointed out in the question. Could you please explain more details?

Answer (score 2):

> An apparent approach: For each metric, read all data for the metric (page by page), write data to new file. But this takes much time, especially when reading data from the file.
>
> Is there any efficient ways?

**Yes.** After you get a working solution, measure it's efficiency, then decide which parts you wish to optimize. What and how you optimize will depend greatly on what results you get here (what are your bottlenecks).

A few generic things to consider:

- if you have one set of steps that read data for a single metric and move it to the output, you should be able to parallelize that (have 20 sets of steps instead of one).
- a 10Gb file will take a bit to process regardless of what hardware you run your code on (concievably, you could run it on a supercomputer but I am ignoring that case). You / your client may accept a slower solution if it displays it's progress / shows a progress bar.
- do not use string comparisons for sorting;

**Edit (addressing comment)**

Consider performing the read as follows:

- create a list of block offset for the blocks you want to read
- create a list of worker threads, of fixed size (for example, 10 workers)
- each idle worker will receive the file name and a block offset, then create a std::ifstream instance on the file, read the block, and return it to a receiving object (and then, request another block number, if any are left).
- read pages should be passed to a central structure that manages/stores pages.

Also consider managing the memory for the blocks separately (for example, allocate chunks of multiple blocks preemptively, when you know the number of blocks to be read).

Comment: I tried the approach. For a file of 5.2 GB, it took around 2h 30 mins (on core i5 & 8 GB RAM system). The bottleneck is reading data that ranges in many pages. Because pages for a single metric might not be consecutive, each fread could read 800 bytes at maximum (1 page). As I saw in the log, for many metrics, the time needs to read whole data were up to 30 seconds.