# Memory mapping a huge file in 32 bit software running on 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have performance problems with reading huge files. I would like to use memory mapping to solve the problems. Input files are up to 10 GB of size, my program (written in C++) is built with 32 bit configuration, the target system is Windows 64 bit and has 24 GB of RAM. Is this possible to map whole a huge file to memory? If yes, how can my program access to the "high" address area (> 0xFFFFFFFF, theoritically, because my program is 32 bit, so pointers are 32 bit also)?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't compile the program in 64 bits?

Comment: The program was written long time ago. It is being upgraded step by step, and 64 bit is in schedule but not right now.

Comment: You can only map the file in chunks see MSDN MapViewOfFile https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx  .  Note that it uses 2 DWORDS (high, low) as an offset into the file for where the view is to begin.  Try mapping < 2GB at a time.

Comment: Why do you think memory mapping will be faster than regular file i/o?  That can be true for certain types of access patterns, but it's not true in the most general cases.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047626/efficiently-read-data-from-a-structured-file-in-c-c for more details about my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  A 32-bit program uses 32-bit pointers that can't go past 4GB, even when running on a 64-bit OS.

One thing that may help a little, though, is to link your program with the [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) option.  By default, 32-bit Windows programs are only able to use *2GB* of the address space, because some programs assume that a pointer's uppermost bit is always zero and use it as a flag to store additional information.  That'd break if Windows started allocating memory above 2GB, so you have to link your program with a special option that tells Windows your program doesn't abuse that bit.  This lets your program use the full 4GB of address space instead of being limited to 2GB.

Comment: I guess the only programs that abuses the top bit so hard and are so significant that MSVC reserves the top bit for them, must be written by MS people themselves.

Comment: The first paragraph is fine, but the one on /LARGEADDRESSAWARE is misleading and irrelevant.  At best, /LARGEADDRESSAWARE gets a 32-bit process 3GB of usable address space, since the top GB is still reserved for the system, as are some chunks in the middle, so even with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE, you still won't have more than 2GB of _contiguous_ space, which isn't going to help duong_dajgja load a 10GB file.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, the 3GB/1GB split is for 32-bit windows using the [`/3GB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) boot option.  64-bit Windows doesn't need that gigabyte at the top of the 32-bit address space, so [large-address-aware 32-bit programs can use the full 4GB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/01/423817.aspx).  (I don't know about whether Windows always allocates stuff in the middle of the address space, though.)

Comment: @Wyzard:  It's misleading to say, "because some programs assume that a pointer's uppermost bit is always zero and use it as a flag to store additional information."  It's irrelevant because 3 or 4 GB of nonconsecutive address space still won't help you map a 10 GB file.

Answer (score 0):

In a 32-bit program, you will never be able to map the whole file at once in a single process, since the address space is 2GB long. What is possible is to map only part of the file at a given moment by playing with `MapViewOfFile` parameters. It is also possible to map the whole file at once with multiple processes mapping 1GB each (since separate processes have separate address spaces), but that would be really impractical to use.

Comment: As you said, for a single process, the address space is 2 GB long, is it possible for a process map 2 different files with each file is 1.5 GB long?

Comment: @duong_dajgja No, with a 2GB address space, you can't map more than 2GB. As you mentioned, it's not a problem of memory, it's about accessing it. 2x1.5GB won't fit in the address space. You might succeed if you can get a 4GB address space, as mentioned in Wyzard's answer.